# Buttons in a pause menu created in canvas in unity not working, even though everything is correct

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a pause menu created in unity. There is a panel and on it, there are three buttons but they do not seem to be working, meaning I can not click on them. Also, interactable of every button is checked and event system is present in the hierarchy.
[Hierarchy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcjGM.png)

[image: an image of resume button in the inspector panel]

Following is the code for the resume button:

```
public void resumegame()
    {
        levemusic.UnPause();
        pausemenu.SetActive(false);
        Cursor.visible = false;
        gameisPaused = false;
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
```

Comment: `even though everything is correct` is a little bit questionable if you also state it isn't working ^^

Comment: Does the button react to interactions at all? E.g. does the color change on hover? Is there maybe some component blocking the input Raycast like e.g. any text or image that has a too big RectTransform ? Make sure that any of the lower button in your hierarchy (those are drawn on top) are really limited to the expected size

Comment: No the color doesn't change. However, i will check whether the components are blocking

Comment: Yeah if it doesn't receive input at all it sounds like another raycast target UI element is on top of it (=lower in the hierarchy) and blocks your input

Answer (score 1):

Either disable this component on the panel

[image: Panel]

Or move the panel object such that it is on top of the hierarchy in the object hierarchy

[image: Panel]